# .call(function) is not executed after transition in d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js, call, transition

In the below code the call method is not executed after the transition on the path and text svg elements. Could you explain me the reason?

The structure of the elements are as below, will help you in understanding the code-

```
<g> //each g tag is an arc component in a donut chart
    <path> //path which defines arc
    <text> //Label for the arc
</g>
```

The following piece of code is doing the rotation animation-

```
var counters = {"i":endIndex};
for(counters.i=endIndex; counters.i>=startIndex;){
    var textPositionC = textPositionX;
    textPositionX = d3.select(arcArray[counters.i]).select("text").attr("transform");

    d3.select((d3.select(arcArray[counters.i]).select("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(301)
        .attrTween("d", tweenRotateRight)[0][0])
        .node
        .parentNode)
        .select("text")
        .attr("transform", textPositionC)
        .style("visibility", "visible")
        .call(function(counters){
            counters.i=counters.i-1;
            if(counters.i<startIndex)
            $('#rightButton').removeClass('disableRotate');
        });
}
```

Comment: Its executed before the completion of the transition, want to execute after the completion of transition

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#each

Comment: Thanks Mark, but here should I be using .call(function) or .each('end', function)? As every selection has only one element in it. And if you see first I'm doing a transform on path element with a transition delay of 301ms, after that i'm selecting the next text node and performing some transform on it as well. My assumption here is transformation on text will be applied after the completion of transformation (including transition delay) on path element. If i'm wrong how can I fix this?